# cURL request with 'User-Agent' header works fine but doesnt work in node with axios/fetch/https

Tags: node.js, http, curl, axios, fetch

When i make a curl request to a website for webscraping with the header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0" it works with status code 200. But when i use it in node js with axios or https or fetch, i get a 403 error. What's going wrong? i cant figure it out?

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers : {
                "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
            }
          });

        return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = 'https://www.google.com';
const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers : {
        "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0"
    }
  });

console.log(response);
```

I tried the above in node. Getting a json response.
Can you update what website you are trying to fetch data.
The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

May be you need to add some token to get authorized